# Google App Engine - How reliable are the logs?

Tags: google-app-engine

How reliable are the Google App Engine logs?

Because logs are optimized for write speed, and the datastore is optimized for read speed, I'm thinking about storing some data by writing it to the logs rather than writing it to the datastore.

If I call `Logger.info("something");`, and the call succeeds, will that log entry definitely show up in the logs?  Or will it sometimes silently fail?

About every hour I'll have my home computer download the logs to persist the data on my home computer.

Comment: If Google had a storage mechanism which was as reliable as datastore, but faster, would they use it for *logs*? ;-) (Actually maybe yes, if the only reason it's faster is that it's "write-once" within some particular scope. But I really doubt that Google is saving the best tech for the logging subsystem, or that it's a good move to exploit logging performance. If saving your data to datastore is too slow, something's probably wrong).

Comment: @Steve Jessop - The datastore is optimized for fast reads, whereas reading from the logs is incredibly slow. Its possible that the logs might be perfectly reliable, I just don't know.  I plan on just taking the log data every hour or so, calculating some stuff from it on my home computer, then updating the datastore with the result of the calculation.  I don't mind if the log data is later thrown away, just as long as I have a chance to download it first.

Comment: Regarding read/write speed, whether it's in datastore or logs you have to write the data once and read it once. Unless you're running one of the top 10 Google apps by volume of datastore traffic, it just seems a bit unlikely that this is a good optimisation. There's probably a better way to use datastore than whatever you're doing that's currently failing your performance criteria.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - I need to write something every single request.  A single datastore put adds about 100ms to the response time (http://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/datastore/2010/03/10#ae-trust-detail-datastore-put-latency).  If logs are reliable, then I save 100ms of cpu time every request.

Comment: latency != CPU time, surely. But OK, if you can measure a 100ms faster response at the browser, I can hardly argue with the results. I share your interest to know whether it's reliable, or whether e.g. faster write speed is at the cost of a possibility of the log write failing to commit, asynchronously, elsewhere in the system where your app never sees it. For example if the Google data center is hit by an EMP 99 milliseconds after your HTTP response leaves the building, will the log entry be any less redundantly stored that a successfully `put` entity would be ;-)

Comment: @Kyle did you consider to write the data using async taskqueues? I find myself in a similar situation and I'm actually evaluating whether to analyze the logs or just write to datastore. So far it seems analyzing the logs it's quite expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's very unlikely, it's *possible* the call could silently fail, because logs are written asynchronously (or else they wouldn't be so fast). If you need reliability, using the [task queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) or [deferred](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred.html) to insert a datastore entity might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'm okay with some rare loss of data, so maybe I'll give it a try.  I'm mainly trying to save quota usage by doing it this way.  I heard on the google group that there is a size limit to the log before it gets flushed, do you know about what that is?

Comment: Hi Nick, I posted a follow up question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427442/google-app-engine-about-how-much-quota-does-a-single-datastore-put-use . If you wouldn't mind taking a look at it.