# Google App Engine - About how much quota does a single datastore put use?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, task-queue

The latency for a datastore put is about 150ms - http://code.google.com/status/appengine/detail/datastore/2010/03/11#ae-trust-detail-datastore-put-latency.

About how much CPUTime is used by a single datastore put with data size of 100 bytes, into an entity that has only 1 property, and no indexes?

Also, does anyone know about how much extra overhead in CPUTime doing this datastore put through the task queue would be?

I plan to do some testing with this later today to figure it out, but if anyone already knows that would help me out :).

Note: This is kind of a follow up to this question: [Google App Engine - How reliable are the logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421075/google-app-engine-how-reliable-are-the-logs).

Comment: @Peter It showed a single datastore put takes about 75ms of CPU time, and about the same amount of latency is added.  I was hoping that latency would be about 75ms but CPU time would actually be only like 20ms or something, but I was wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the poster said in the comment, a single datastore put takes about 75ms of CPU time, and about the same amount of latency.